# css selector fails with 'id class img'

Tags: html, css

I'm wondering why the following selector won't work.

The html:

```
<div id="commissie">
    <img class="logo" src="http://www.dalcanton.it/tito/code/alcaze/foobar.png">
 </div>
```

The css:

```
#commissie .logo img  {
    margin-top: 100px;
}
```

So simple as that, can someone tell?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using it in wrong manner. `.logo` class is used for `img`.

use like this.

```
#commissie img.logo {
    margin-top: 100px;
}
```

Comment: @clankill3r  you may close this question by accepting the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing mistake at here,

```
#commissie .logo img
```

Change this to,

```
#commissie img.logo 
{
margin-top: 100px;
}
```

**Before** :

[image]

**AFTER**:

[image]